# Bridgecontext can not be cast to Application

Tags: android

I create customview, then get Application from context. But it show error: 
java.lang.ClassCastException:com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.BridgeContext cannot be cast to com.ibsv.cheerupkpi.utilities.CheerupKPIApplication

This is my code:

```
public  CheerupKPIApplication mApplication;

public MenuBottomBar(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.menu_bottom_bar, this);

mApplication = (CheerupKPIApplication) context.getApplicationContext();
```

}

Please help me!

Comment: This is in the layout editor in Android Studio, correct?

Comment: Yes, it in the layout editor in Android Studio.

Answer (score 2):

The layout editor in Android Studio only mimics the layout inflation using a sort of mock Context. It doesn't actually have a real Context like you would on a real device, and certainly doesn't have an Application Context since there is no Application running (you aren't even in the runtime of a device).

You can use `isInEditMode()` in your custom view to avoid running code that doesn't work in the layout editor. In this case you would need to skip the line

`mApplication = (CheerupKPIApplication) context.getApplicationContext();`

as well as anything that needs to use `mApplication` to do an initial measure, layout, and draw.

Comment: If I ignore this issue on layout editor, it still work well on emulator and real device.

Comment: @DuyenHangKim Is that a question, or are you just affirming that it worked for you?